# sum of exponential vs exponential of sums

Tags: analysis, inequality, jensen-inequality

Let $x_1,\cdots,x_k\in (0,1]$ are $k$ reals such that $\sum_{i=1}^kx_i > 1/2$. Since $f(x)=\exp(-x)$ is convex function, from [Jensen's inequality](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Jensen%27s_inequality), we have that $\sum_{i=1}^k\exp(-x_i) \geq k.\exp(-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^kx_i}{k})$. Is there any reverse inequality, meaning can $\sum_{i=1}^k\exp(-x_i)$ be upper bounded by some expression involving $\exp(-\sum_{i=1}^kx_i)$?